# RxJs: is it possible to do delay with various time while using retryWhen

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Consider the following stream

```
this.service.doSomeRequest(params).pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        delay(2000),
        take(10)
    )
)
```

I want delay time be different depending on number of attempt. I've tried the following

```
let getDelayTime = (index) => {
    console.log('index', index);
    return index * 2 * 1000;
}

let retryCount = 0;
this.service.doSomeRequest(params).pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        delay(getDelayTime(retryCount)),
        tap(() => retryCount++),
        take(10)
    )
)
```

Still `console.log('index', index)` fires only one time.

So how can make delay time depend on number of attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delayWhen` passing the result of your calculation to a `timer`.

```
let getDelayTime = (index) => {
    console.log('index', index);
    return index * 2 * 1000;
}

let retryCount = 0;
this.service.doSomeRequest(params).pipe(
    retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        delayWhen(() => timer(getDelayTime(retryCount))),
        tap(() => retryCount++),
        take(10)
    ))
)
```